# Created new branch without committing changes. Lost the changes

Tags: git, commit

I accidentally created a new branch from existing branch, without committing the existing branch changes. Strangely, Git didn't prompt there is uncommitted changes. Now I cannot find the days of work. It's not in the Git site or in local.

Searched in Git repo. Only last committed version is there, as expected. Searched in local storage and it is also changed.

Comment: **Default behavior** when creating a new branch (say, with `git checkout -b some-branch`) is not to mess up with the changes that you have laying around your working tree... it would create the new branch and keep everything _as is_. **However**, there are options that override this (like `git checkout -f`) so _depending_ on the options that you used when you created the branch/checked out, it _might_ have been lost. Do you have the command you used to create/checkout the new branch? Or even better, the command and the output?

Answer (score 1):

Git will never let you loose your work unless you specify you want to do so, usually with some `--force` or `--hard` parameter.

When you have uncommitted changes, you can create new branch anytime and continue in your work, with all your work intact, in the new branch.

If you're in this new branch, try running `git diff` and you should see all your work there, waiting to be committed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. In the new branch also didnt had the changes i have done. But fortunately, I found the changes in stash.

Comment: @Damith then you probably have autostash enabled. Also, commit more often. As in: multiple times per day, not once every few days. Do you leave Word open for days without saving and uploading to the cloud?